# How to get properties of a characteristics while developing a BLE Application

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-studio-3.0

I am developing a Bluetooth Low Energy APP: The snippet

```
            if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                final int charaProp = mNotifyCharacteristic.getProperties();

                if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                    mBluetoothLEService.readCharacteristic(mNotifyCharacteristic);
                }
                if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                    mBluetoothLEService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, true);
                }
            }
```

From my knowledge mNotifyCharacteristic.getProperties() should return the integer value 2, since towards the BLE Device  Read properties is set. Therefore the value of charaProp should be 2.However getProperties(); returns 0 because of which readCharacteristic  fails. Any help will be appriciated over this.

Comment: The returning of 0 means it is not a readable characteristic. Check which characteristic you are reading.

Comment: On the BLE device I set : characteristic properties as NOTIFY then getproperties(); fetches 16 , which is correct. When I change characteristics properties on the BLE device from NOTIFY to READ, getproperties() is fetching 0 instead of 2. So I am a bit confused here

Comment: On the BLE side I have given AT_BLE_CHAR_NOTIFY | AT_BLE_CHAR_READ as the properties. On the app I fetch getproperties which 16.How is that possible

Comment: What is get properties? And what does the return 16 mean?

Comment: Hi @ThomasMorris , Thanks for the response. On the BLE device  I specify :- csc_inst.endpoint_chars.properties = (AT_BLE_CHAR_NOTIFY | AT_BLE_CHAR_READ);......This means endpoint_chars.properties has a decimal value of 18. On the app I give a command final int charaProp = mNotifyCharacteristic.getProperties();....This returns a value of 16. Therefore there is a mismatch between the int value of the properties of a particular characteristic towards the server and client side.

Comment: That does seem very odd, what I recommend is looking through the debugger to ensure that your are view the correct characteristic. Aka check the UUID ensure it is the characteristic value and not the service.

Comment: @ThomasMorris I am not sure how, but its fixed now. Earlier i  gave csc_inst.endpoint_chars.properties = (AT_BLE_CHAR_NOTIFY which had a dec value of 16. Probably it gets saved somewhere in the android studio and doesnt refresh/update after we make changes.

Comment: It could be in your oncreate it does not get updated. In which case I recommend setting the values to null until they are filled via your get services and characteristic functions. Then do a null check before writing to catch the error.